# JVM enough memory but frequency full gc

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

JVM Options:
-Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:PermSize=70M -XX:MaxPermSize=70M

**jstat -gc 8260 5000**

S0C:512.0  S1C:512.0   S0U:0.0    S1U:0.0   EC:174080.0   EU:0.0    OC:349696.0   OU:45191.1   PC:71680.0   PU:34882.2   YGC:2216225   YGCT:6754.909   FGC:2216144   FGCT:160651.466   GCT:167406.375

S0C:512.0  S1C:512.0   S0U:0.0    S1U:64.0  EC:174080.0   EU:0.0    OC:349696.0   OU:45187.3   PC:71680.0   PU:34882.2   YGC:2216253   YGCT:6755.047   FGC:2216172   FGCT:160653.488   GCT:167408.535

S0C:512.0  S1C:512.0   S0U:0.0    S1U:128.0 EC:174080.0   EU:0.0    OC:349696.0   OU:45189.6   PC:71680.0   PU:34882.2   YGC:2216281   YGCT:6755.180   FGC:2216200   FGCT:160655.542   GCT:167410.721

S0C:512.0  S1C:512.0   S0U:0.0    S1U:0.0   EC:174080.0   EU:1775.6 OC:349696.0   OU:45187.3   PC:71680.0   PU:34882.2   YGC:2216308   YGCT:6755.309   FGC:2216227   FGCT:160657.627   GCT:167412.936

S0C:512.0  S1C:512.0   S0U:128.0  S1U:0.0   EC:174080.0   EU:0.0    OC:349696.0   OU:45187.3   PC:71680.0   PU:34882.2   YGC:2216336   YGCT:6755.444   FGC:2216255   FGCT:160659.701   GCT:167415.146

Why JVM frequency full gc happened?

Comment: The program builds a udp server, which receive and analysis packages(less than 1024 bytes). **After 3-5 days works fine**, this happends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When heap and stack memory looks good, try to find memory leak about "Direct Memory". In my case, part of Netty5-ByteBuf didn't released.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell, but one possible explanation is that you are repeatedly allocating and discarding very large arrays.

If I am interpreting the stats correctly, the Eden space is 174MB, the Survivor spaces are 0.5MB, and the Old space is 349MB.  If you allocate an array that is too large to put into the Eden space, it will be allocated straight into Old space.  If the Old space fills, that may trigger a full GC.

How big is "big"?  Well it is complicated, because there is also the issue of the TLAB and its size, the `-XX:PretenureSizeThreshold` option and differences between different kinds of GC.  Read  ["Java Garbage Collection Distilled"](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/java-garbage-collection-distilled.html) by Martin Thompson to get you started on the issues.

---

If this is not the problem then you need to do a deeper investigation of what is happening in your heap.  Figure out what the mix of objects is, their rates and patterns of allocation / disposition, etc to try and figure out why so many are ending up in the Old space.

> After 3-5 days works fine, this happens

That tends to suggest that something is building up in your application's in-memory data structures over those three to five days of operation.  Investigate that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure that there is no "big" arrays, the program builds a udp server, which receive and analysis packages(less than 1024 bytes). **After 3-5 days running**, this happends.

Comment: Are using `ArrayList` or `StringBuilder`?  Or some other data structure that uses arrays behinds the scenes?

Comment: May have, but there couldn't be a 'big' array, cause only after 3-5 days works fine this happens(the program receive 10-20 small packages per second, individual from each other).

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Gixed.  Ganks

Comment: @vzyh - That doesn't necessary follow.  For example, if you have a data structure that is accumulating more and more data over time, then there could be arrays that are growing in size.

Comment: @StephenC pet hate of mine, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your survivor spaces are very small. Just 512KB. If the survivor space fills up on a clean up of the Eden space it triggers a Full GC.

As your Eden spaces is ~300 x larger, I would be surprised if they were not filling up.

I would check that you are not creating a lot of very short lived objects which is why the JVM thinks hardly anything survives.

For example, see if you can parse/process your UDP packet without creating objects.

Comment: I didn't set survivorRatio option, the actual size was determined by JVM. And I try removed  "-Xms512M -Xmx512M -XX:PermSize=70M -XX:MaxPermSize=70M" options, then the size changed to 1024, until now 2 days works fine, I will keep update at future

Comment: @vzyh setting tuning parameters often have unintended concequences which can be due to an odd interaction. Note unless you only have 2 GB in your machine you will have increased the heap size which defaults to 1/4 of main memory.

Comment: After setting -Xmn512m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, at the beginning seems fine, S0 and S1 both 40M Eden space 400M, but one days later S0 and S0 changed to 16M and Eden space changed to 480M, so JVM was adjusting these parameters when the program is running. I guess one or two days later S0 and S1 will be 512K again.

Comment: using jprofiler I found logger created too much char[], about 10mins 500M, YGC will clear them all, they wont be able to live in survivor space, I guess that's why JVM auto increase the Eden space.
But I still find nothing about frequency full gc.

Comment: @vzyh creating a high amount of short lived char [] suggests to me you should try to optimise your String handling.

Comment: I found it! Direct Memory not released correctly.
ByteBuffer jdk(seems can be clean by gc) and ByteBuf of Netty5(cant be clean by gc).